# How do I find a transaction by txID (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

How do I find a transaction by txID? In version 1.4(Fabric Node SDK) there was a queryTransaction method, but in 2.0 it is not, is there any replacement for it?

P.S I tried to get the transaction this way, but I get nothing

```
const result = await ctx.stub.getState(txId)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you get nothing, it is probably because the transaction does not exist in the state (it has not been saved to CouchDB/LevelDB). You have probably endorsed (simulated) the transaction, but it has not been committed yet.

Comment: If I request the state using the key that I specified when writing, then I get my data, and if I specify txId, nothing comes. You say that it is not commited, what should I do after the transaction is submitted? P.s thanks for the answer

Comment: Ah, OK. Your key is different from your tx ID, so your tx ID is not saved on the state, only in the block chain. Thus, forget about `getState`, it has no sense. For any reason `queryTransaction` seems to have dissapeared from node.js SDK (but not from GO or Java SDKs). Maybe you must wait...

Comment: Maybe, as a workaround, you can get the corresponding event (transaction event or custom event) by the tx ID and extract the necessary information from your event.